# A book of mystery - Page II

Tags: riddle, story

I AM SORRY ABOUT THE LAST PUZZLE IN WHICH I MESSED UP THE NUMBERS BUT BEASTLYGERBIL EVENTUALLY GOT THE ANSWER WHICH WAS 'THIS CODE BELONGS TO SAM'. ENJOY!

Once the first riddle was solved
The question turned bold
And what popped into view 
Was a brand new clue:

> 110 111   1 111   11 1010 10 0 111 10 01 0100 100 011110 000   00 000 0100 00 10 110 1 111 10

It looks like some kind of binary code
But the answer seems as slippery as a toad

**Note that the answer to the first page will provide help solving this one**

It hasn't had much attention so I'll add a hint:

> The code in which it is written is not the one that you first think

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message says

> Go to McDonald's Islington

because

> it is Morse code, 1=dah and 0=dit, except that there is a typo and there is a `10 0` that should be `100` so it really says "Go to McNeonald's Islington"

and I learned

> that an apostrophe in Morse is •----•

Comment: Maybe it's the neon-bathed version of that restaurant.